# Mixamo doesn't give animations

Tags: import, error, .fbx, motion-capture

I tried to install some more Mixamo animations but when I load them into blender they have no animation and are slightly transparent.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see there are only two keyframes because there is no animation

Comment: There are lots of YT videos on using Mixamo animations in Blender. There's a whole series of Mixamo to/from Blender tutorials from CGDive [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cgdive+mixamo) which should help.

Answer (score 0):

I just made an account because I couldn't find an answer for this anywhere else, and after some messing around I found a solution, so I thought I'd share.

The problem with the animation only having two keyframes seems to have something to do with the armature.

Here are the steps I took which fixed this:

1. Open the original model file (the one you uploaded to Mixamo)
2. Delete the armature (first make sure it's not in any distorted pose - use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, also, on the off chance this doesn't work for you, maybe make a backup file so you don't lose your armature permanently)
3. Export to FBX
4. Upload the new FBX file to Mixamo (it should automatically take you through a simple rigging process if you upload without any bones)
5. Using your newly rigged model, download the animations you wanted to use
6. Import them into blender
7. They now should play the way they're supposed to.